# client.recordings.each is not a function in Node.js

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

This is my code, I have installed Twilio and express. But I can't seem to access client.recordings.Could someone help me out?

```
var twilio = require('twilio');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.listen(8000, () => {
   console.log('Server started!');
});

app.route('/api/cats/:name').get((req, res) => {
   /*const requestedCatName = req.params['name'];
   res.send({ name: requestedCatName });*/
   const accountSid = 'AC02f0596174c674c015bc697a14f2e41d';
   const authToken = '';
   const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
   client.recordings.each({
                    dateCreated: new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0))
                  },
                      recordings => res.send({ name: recordings.sid })
                  );
});
```

This is the error that I get

TypeError: client.recordings.each is not a function
    at app.route.get (/Users/jerinjacobcherian/Desktop/feedback_backend/server.js:15:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jerinjacobcherian/Desktop/feedback_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/jerinjacobcherian/Desktop/feedback_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/jerinjacobcherian/Desktop/feedback_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jerinjacobcherian/Desktop/feedback_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/jerinjacobcherian/Desktop/feedback_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/Users/jerinjacobcherian/Desktop/feedback_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/Users/jerinjacobcherian/Desktop/feedback_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jerinjacobcherian/Desktop/feedback_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/Users/jerinjacobcherian/Desktop/feedback_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the syntax:

new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0))

Visiting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

month
An integer between 0 and 11 representing the month.

Have you tried:
new Date(Date.UTC(2018, **7**, 8, 0, 0, 0))

Comment: I did. But the error is still the same. I have shared the error message now